# d3.csv promise pending and getting its data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is my first time to ask StackOverflow - I'm new to D3 and had used v5 for this matter

I have already been searching for days and can't find anything. if there's an existing one please help me directly to an exact answer. thank you so much for the help!

---

### intro: just got a sample data for use:

```
Wafer,N Rows,Product Yield,Endline Yield,Mid_Yield
7G650,10,91.18%,99.70%,94.27%
7G651,10,88.41%,98.11%,95.54%
7G652,10,92.08%,97.56%,98.58%
7G657,10,87.71%,97.76%,95.77%
```

---

first off - before, my code was like below:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      var yield = d3.csv("http://server/trend/data.csv",
                       function(data, i) {
                          return {
                             waf : data.Wafer,
                             seq : i,
                           yield : +data["Product Yield"].replace(/%/g, "")
                       };
      });
      console.log(yield);
   });
</script>
```

and when I checked at the console (chrome) - I can see my data. it's just that it needs a promise implementation

[image]

so i searched for some solution and here's my code now:

```
var yield = d3.csv("http://server/trend/data.csv",
                function(data, i) {
                    return {
                         waf : data.Wafer,
                         seq : i,
                       yield : +data["Product Yield"].replace(/%/g, "")
                    };
                 }).then(function(data){
                       console.log(data);
             });
```

I could still see my filtered data from console.log(data),

[image]

but when I query from outside d3.csv using the "yield" variable

```
console.log(yield);
```

values are now undefined

[image]

so sorry for the trouble, my boss is about to kill me.. i will need this filtered data for my trend, and soon will add a pareto chart.. thanks in advance and more power to stackoverflow -

Comment: You cannot use `yield` as a variable or property name—it's a [keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield).

Comment: thanks @Thilina Nakkawita for including my images directly on my question :)

Comment: thanks @altocumulus for this info... i never knew that yield is one of its keywords -

Answer (score -1):

edit: following @altocumulus 's comment

I believe you may be after:

```
var resultYield;

d3.csv("http://server/trend/data.csv",
  function(data, i) {
    return {
      waf : data.Wafer,
      seq : i,
      yield : +data["Product Yield"].replace(/%/g, "")
    };
  }).then(function(data){
    resultYield = data;
    console.log(resultYield);
  })
```

re: using yield / return as keys for object literals:

```js
const test = {
  yield: 'yield',
  return : 'return'
}

const getTest = () => ({
  yield: 'getYield',
  return: 'getReturn'
})

const getTest2 = function(){
  return {
    yield: 'getYield2',
    return: 'getReturn2'
  }
}

console.log(test, getTest(), getTest2())
```

Comment: Still there is a `yield` in the object literal.

Comment: as a key? I didn't think there was anything wrong with it?

Comment: Good point. Never thought about that since I generally consider using a keyword as an identifier a bad idea. Related: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-properties, [*"Rules for unquoted JavaScript Object Literal Keys?"*](/q/9367572).

Comment: ` ECMAScript 3 didn’t allow the use of unquoted reserved words as property names.` I see  your point.

Comment: hi @pandamakes, thanks for your answer, i tried your code & changed all yield keyword except for csv-col-title

`var resultYield;
 d3.csv("http://localhost:5001/data.csv", function(data, i) {
    return { waf : data.Wafer,
                seq : i,
                 yld : +data["SDPT Yield"].replace(/%/g, "")
               };
     }).then(function(data){
           resultYield = data;
           console.log(resultYield);
 });`

resultYield works inside d3.csv, but not outside still- 
i need to get this kind of data
---
`resultYield = [{ waf: "7G650", seq: 1, yld: 94.27 }]`

Comment: unfortunately, that is the case with a Promise or a callback function. Unless you are interested in looking into [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), you will have to work with [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)